# Transparent background turns white

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uiimageview

I'm uploading an image with a transparent background to firebase. The background becomes white when I downloaded it somehow. Any idea how to fix this?

Here's my putData function.

```
let uploadData = imageview.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75)
let uploadTask = imagesRef.putData(uploadData!, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
    guard let metadata = metadata else {
        return
    }
```

And here is the download function.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: imageURL as! String)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print("ERROR LOADING IMAGES FROM URL: \(String(describing: error))")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            imageView.image = UIImage()
        }
        return
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
            imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: NSString(string: imageURL!))
            imageView.image = downloadedImage
        }
    }
}).resume()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm uploading an image with a transparent background to firebase. The
>   background becomes white when I downloaded it somehow. Any idea how to
>   fix this?

You're doing it right, except you're getting getting a **JPEG** instead of **PNG** data ;) Remember that JPEG does not support transparent BG.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You're very much welcome. You can mark this as an answer if this solved your question. :)